# Using Distinct Clause with expressions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to use the distinct clause to add these two values together, but when I do it still gives me two separate rows. Ultimately I want to add these two rows together.

[A screenshot of the table view from my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9A4O.png)

Basically this is a database that keeps track of books, pages, quantity, price, etc. I'm trying to find the total value of books that fit a certain genre (nonfiction), and are over a certain price threshold. I then multiply these two together to get the value.

There's two records in my database that fit this description, and it is displaying the individual values for both of these records

```
 SELECT DISTINCT  Sum([Price]*[Quantity]) AS Total_Value
 FROM Merchandise INNER JOIN Book ON Merchandise.MerchID = Book.ISBN
 GROUP BY Book.Genre, Merchandise.Price, Merchandise.Quantity
 HAVING (((Book.Genre)="Nonfiction") AND ((Merchandise.Price)>18));
```

Comment: Don't tag products not involved... Are you really using MySQL and SQL Server and Access???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I submitted this answer based on the MS Access tags.  However, I think it should work the same in SQL Server, but no idea about MySQL.

`GROUP BY Book.Genre, Merchandise.Price, Merchandise.Quantity` asks for a separate row for each unique combination of those 3 fields.  Since you want only one row, remove `Merchandise.Price` and `Merchandise.Quantity` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Also `DISTINCT` is not useful in a `GROUP BY` query, so you can remove that, too.

```sql
SELECT Sum([Price]*[Quantity]) AS Total_Value
FROM Merchandise INNER JOIN Book ON Merchandise.MerchID = Book.ISBN
GROUP BY Book.Genre
HAVING Book.Genre='Nonfiction' AND Merchandise.Price>18;
```

If you change the `HAVING` to a `WHERE` clause, you can exclude the rows you don't want evaluated before doing the `GROUP BY` aggregation:

```sql
SELECT Sum([Price]*[Quantity]) AS Total_Value
FROM Merchandise INNER JOIN Book ON Merchandise.MerchID = Book.ISBN
WHERE Book.Genre='Nonfiction' AND Merchandise.Price>18
GROUP BY Book.Genre;
```

Actually, for this particular query, I suspect you don't need `GROUP BY` at all:

```sql
SELECT Sum([Price]*[Quantity]) AS Total_Value
FROM Merchandise INNER JOIN Book ON Merchandise.MerchID = Book.ISBN
WHERE Book.Genre='Nonfiction' AND Merchandise.Price>18;
```